# Groovy: splitting multi-line string

Tags: regex, groovy

I have got a file that looks like this:

```
FOoo 
/
Bar
/
Bar foo Bar / asda
/
Lorem ipsum
ipsum lorem;
/
```

I want to split the text by a regex `^/$`, meaning line beginning and ending with delimeter `/`. I have tried various variants including `text.split(/^\/$/)` but it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `text.split(/(?m)^\/$/)`, or even `text.split(/(?m)[\r\n]+\/$[\r\n]*/)`

Comment: What does it ?m mean? Post it as I answer and I will mark it. The first one worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy regex (that actually uses Java regex library), you may use a [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) inline embedded flag `(?m)` that will make `^` match a start of the line and `$` the end of the line (rather than a whole string):

> Multiline mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression `(?m)`.

Use

```
text.split(/(?m)^\/$/)
            ^^^^
```